# How to set variable in where condition in codeigniter if variable is set?

Tags: codeigniter

Below is my code

```
$state = $data['state'];
$this->db->select("state")->from('table')
    ->where('en_movingfrom_state', $state)
    ->where('status', 3);
```

I want to execute this query, if `$state` is set then where condition will execute.

So please help me how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$state = $data['state'];

// checking `$state has set`
if (isset($state) && (trim($state) != '')) {
    $this->db->where('en_movingfrom_state', $state)
}
$result = $this->db->select("state")->from('table')
    ->where('status', 3)
    ->get()->result_array();

// Output
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use isset() function to check whether $state is set

```
$state = $data['state'];
$this->db->select("state")->from('table');
if(isset($state) && $state != ""){
   $this->db->where('en_movingfrom_state', $state);
}
$this->db->where('status', 3);
$this->db->get()->result_array();
```